# How to remove specific part(redundant querystring) of string in php?

Tags: php, preg-replace

How to remove multiple redundant query string from url?

Hence, like below string,

Url:

```
localhost.com/en_ar/body?products_type=235&treatment=132?product_type=235&treatment=132&__from_store=en_bh
```

Resultant Url:

```
localhost.com/en_ar/body?product_type=235&treatment=132&__from_store=en_bh
```

How to remove first portion of content from string between `?content?` if exist in querystring using php.

In our case remove content `?products_type=235&treatment=132?` from string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ca use the following regex([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/5YsplJ/1)):

```
(\?(?<=\?).*(?=\?))
```

It will look around for `?` and match all content between 2 `?`, along with the 1st `?`.

And the following PHP Code([DEMO](https://eval.in/918110)):

```
$str = "localhost.com/en_ar/body?products_type=235&treatment=132?product_type=235&treatment=132&__from_store=en_bh";
$newStr = preg_replace('/(\?(?<=\?).*(?=\?))/', '', $str);
var_dump($newStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether you have 1, 2, or more "sets of querystrings" in your url, my pattern/method will match/consume all of them but only capture the last.  For this reason, there will only actually be 1 replacement performed, and the replacement text will be the captured substring (`$1`).

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d185f37c18a8fb5ad269435ac58cf75752f1847c))

```
$url='localhost.com/en_ar/body?abcd?products_type=235&treatment=1‌​32?product_type=235&‌​treatment=132&__from‌​_store=en_bh';

echo preg_replace('/(\?[^?]*)+/','$1',$url);
```

Output:

```
localhost.com/en_ar/body?product_type=235&‌​treatment=132&__from‌​_store=en_bh
```

Pattern Explanation: (**Just 14 steps**: [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S9zHLI/3/))

```
/        // pattern delimiter
(        // start capture group
  \?     // match a question mark
  [^?]*  // greedily match zero or more non-question marks
)+       // end capture group -- repeat one or more times
/        // pattern delimiter
```

Comment: $url = "localhost.com/en_ar/body?abcd?products_type=235&treatment=132?product_type=235&treatment=132&__from_store=en_bh";
 echo preg_replace('/\?[^?]*/','',$url,1);

Comment: output will be like, localhost.com/en_ar/body?product_type=235&treatment=132&__from_store=en_bh
 means all query string except last will be purged.

Comment: I have made a final edit to my answer.  I have removed the old patterns and left only the best one for your task.  If you have questions, please ask.